# java.net.SocketException connection reset error on Android 11+

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, socketexception

My app crashes extremaly often on this error.
**java.net.SocketException connection reset **

I have no any specified line in Stacktrace to write that block here.
I mean there are some informations and error line numbers but none of them are written by me, it's library issue I guess?

It's weird, because if it's my fault in code, why does app crash for Android 11+ only?

I use Retrofit2 library for network calls.

This is a Stacktrace.

`Fatal Exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:215) at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:144) at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:945) at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:909) at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readUntilDataAvailable(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:824) at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:797) at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140) at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237) at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:47) at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$AbstractSource.read(Http1Codec.java:363) at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource.read(Http1Codec.java:453) at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:47) at okio.ForwardingSource.read(ForwardingSource.java:35) at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$ExceptionCatchingResponseBody$1.read(OkHttpCall.java:288) at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:439) at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:291) at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:355) at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:181) at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184) at okhttp3.ResponseBody$BomAwareReader.read(ResponseBody.java:259) at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:1289) at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextQuotedValue(JsonReader.java:1029) at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:814) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$15.read(TypeAdapters.java:380) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$15.read(TypeAdapters.java:368) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:39) at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27) at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:225) at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:121) at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206) at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)`

I was seeking very long time to find, where was my error but I couldn't.
I tried to increase Timeouts, because sometimes I get **Socket Closed ** exception as well

Comment: Which version of OkHttp and Retrofit2 are you using?

Comment: implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'.

I have no okHttp dependency. Should I have it?

Comment: `2.6.0` is 4.5 years old, Android 11 is 3 years old; this might indicate a problem between them. My suggestion would be to upgrade to Retrofit `2.9.0` for now and see how it goes from there. If you can't upgrade it for some reason, Retrofit `2.6.0` uses OkHttp `3.12.0` which you could try to enforce it to `3.12.13`. This might fix the error if it's OkHttp's problem (or create a new one of course).

Comment: When there are updates, Gradle tells me to update, but it didn't in this case :D I thought it was the latest one ;d. Thanks, I will try

Comment: Let me know if that was the case; I'll post it as an answer if so, to help other people who might come across this crash as well.

Comment: When I test app on Emulator or one of my devices, everything works perfectly, but when I push it on Release, I get these errors in Crashlytics.
It means, I have to wait until they confirm my release and after a while, I will check Crashlytics.
This is a only way I guess to test

Comment: I'm having the same problem, someone fixed that?